# Nav links broken and <s showing as errors in VS Code

Tags: html, css

I'm building my website directly in HTML, CSS, and JS for the first time. Everything was working perfectly until I signed up for an iOS app called Clone, which I synced with my GitHub account. Inside my faq.html file, I added one space between a link and a word in a paragraph, just as a test.

Afterward, the nav menu on the FAQ page broke and all the <s turned red in VS Code. At the suggestion of @Samirovic, I changed the page icon img src to include _s instead of spaces, which fixed the < errors.

But the URL problem is still happening. The nav menu works on every page except for the FAQ page, which I updated in Clone. On that page, I still get a 404 error page and the URL is doubled within quotes for some reason (which is what causes the error).

URL Example: [https://studiooriley.github.io/“https://studiooriley.github.io/contact”](https://studiooriley.github.io/%E2%80%9Chttps://studiooriley.github.io/contact%E2%80%9D)

I can't figure out why using the Clone app to add a single space to an FAQ question would cause these issues. I have triple-checked my nav links and can confirm that they're correct. I've been researching for the last six hours and can't find any way to fix this or even anyone else with the same issue.

I would love any help you can provide! I will admit, I'm very new to coding and GitHub, and I didn't understand branches until now, so this all happened in my main branch. I have since made a couple of adjustments in a new branch and in the main branch. I hope you can help. Thank you!

[Here's a picture of my HTML in VS Code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K0hq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the **spaces** in the image name inside the **src** , you must use **_** between words

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I tried adding _s and renaming the image to match. It produced no change. (Also, many of the other pages still show the image fine with the spaces. So I'm not sure I understand.)

Any other ideas?